# How to use mutableStateListOf in compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Items get displayed as duplicates when I use `remember` with `mutableStateListOf`. so whats the right way of creating a mutable list that can hold a list of data classes in a composable.

sample code:

```
@Composable
fun WallpapersDetailScreen{
   val items  =   remember {
        mutableStateListOf<MultiFabItem>() 
    } 

 items.addAll( listOf(
     MultiFabItem(
         identifier = FabIdentifier.FAVOURITE.name,
         icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.heart),
         label = "favourite"
     ),

     MultiFabItem(
         identifier = FabIdentifier.SET_AS_WALLPAPER.name,
         icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.wallpaper),
           label = "Set As Wallpaper"
         )
   )
    }
```

Comment: What do you want this list for? Is `MultiFabItem` a composable function or normal data class?

Comment: the list is for MultiFLoatingActionButton items.. MultiFabItem is a normal data class... but It takes in Icon as a parameter of type ImageBitmap.imageResource which has to be in a composable function.. that's why I had to define the list in the composable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding item on each recomposition with

```
items.addAll( listOf(
     MultiFabItem(
         identifier = FabIdentifier.FAVOURITE.name,
         icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.heart),
         label = "favourite"
     ),

     MultiFabItem(
         identifier = FabIdentifier.SET_AS_WALLPAPER.name,
         icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.wallpaper),
           label = "Set As Wallpaper"
         )
   )
```

You can add your items inside `remember` only on composition and calling ImageBitmap.imageResource before adding to list. imageResource uses `remember` under the hood so you don't have to worry for re-instantiation of images

```
   val heartBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.heart)
   val wallpaperBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.wallpaper)

   val items = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<MultiFabItem>().apply{
            addAll( listOf(
         MultiFabItem(
             identifier = FabIdentifier.FAVOURITE.name,
             icon = heartBitmap,
             label = "favourite"
         ),
    
         MultiFabItem(
             identifier = FabIdentifier.SET_AS_WALLPAPER.name,
             icon = wallpaperBitmap,
               label = "Set As Wallpaper"
             )
       )
        } 
    }
```

Other option is simply checking if items is empty if so add items then.

```
if (items.isEmpty()) {
    items.addAll(
        listOf(
            MultiFabItem(
                identifier = FabIdentifier.FAVOURITE.name,
                icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.heart),
                label = "favourite"
            ),

            MultiFabItem(
                identifier = FabIdentifier.SET_AS_WALLPAPER.name,
                icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.wallpaper),
                label = "Set As Wallpaper"
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: HI thanks, but im passing icon of type ImageBitmap to the list and it states that: Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a Composable function... so when I use .apply{}   I'm unable to pass the icon... i get this error::::  Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun <T> remember(calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)

Comment: You can add items once by checking if your list is empty or use initial function i suggested by instantiating bitmaps out of remember. ImageBitmap.imageResource uses remember under the hood, that's why it's a @Composable function so you don't have to worry about images being instantiated on each recomposition